# Send RTP packet (stream) to server over internet

Tags: android, protocols, rtp

There are so many posts about rtsp protocol, generating rtp packets from android. I wrote a code which can generate rtp packet (stream) and send (unicast / broadcast) to local network. My question is how can i send the packets (stream) to server over Internet? As much i know we can't unicast to a server over inetnet from a local device (have private ip).

```
Android camera ----> RTP PACKETS -----------------------------------------------> SERVER
                                                     Internet
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The router is responsible for this. In fact your router which has access to the internet has a public ip address which everyone shares behind the private network. That is how I am typing to you. Your android needs to have internet access to someone's network. The server will then contact that router since it will know its public ip address and your router will send those packets to your android.